# Recursive removal of arrays inside javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
{ name: ["Jimmy","Jill"], age: [23, 42], location: { city: ["LA", "NYC"] }
```

For every object key there is an array value with 2 entries (always). What I'm trying to do is to recreate the object by plucking the 2nd item in the arrays. But I want this to happen recursively. So the output would be:

```
{ name: "Jill", age: 42, location: { city: "NYC" }
```

I have tried iterating through the object using `Object.keys()` but this doesn't appear to give me nested keys. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to tackle this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why isn't `location` an array like this `[{city: 'LA'}, {city: 'NY'}]`? How do fields nested deeper than 1 level work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this considered okay? This only works if we assume every prop would either be an Array of a plain Object.

```js
let o = { name: ["Jimmy","Jill"], age: [23, 42], location: { city: ["LA", "NY"] }}

function rec(obj) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] instanceof Array) {
            obj[key] = obj[key][1]
        } else {
            obj[key] = rec(obj[key])
        }
    }
    return obj
}

rec(o)
console.dir(o)
```

Or even this? (allows existence of array that contains objects and plain primitive entries)

```js
let o = {
    primitive: 10,
    name: ["Jimmy","Jill"],
    age: [23, 42],
    location: {
        city: ["LA", "NY"],
        test: [
            {prop1: ['1', '2']},
            {prop2: ['A', 'B']}
        ]
    }
}

function rec(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        return rec(obj[1])
    } else if (obj instanceof Object) {
        for (let key in obj) {
            obj[key] = rec(obj[key])
        }
        return obj
    } else {
        return obj
    }
}

rec(o)
console.dir(o)
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: Also for anyone else seeing this, I was looking for the 2nd item in the arrays so `rec(obj[1])` does the trick.

Comment: @GivP Yeah I totally ignored that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to filter during parsing:

```js
j = '{ "name": ["Jimmy","Jill"], "age": [23, 42], "location": { "city": ["LA", "NYC"] }}'

o = JSON.parse(j, (k, v) => v.constructor === Array ? v.pop() : v)

console.log( o )
```

Comment: Lovely and elegant!

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here's a "functional" option to consider. Would need to be modified to accommodate any edge cases.

```
const reducer = input =>
  Object.entries(input).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) =>
      value instanceof Array ? { ...acc, ...{ [key]: value[1] } } : { ...acc, ...reducer(value) },
    {}
  );

const input = { name: ["Jimmy", "Jill"], age: [23, 42], location: { city: ["LA", "NYC"] } };
const reduced = reducer(input);

console.log(reduced); // Output: { name: 'Jill', age: 42, city: 'NYC' }
```